# Selenose - django, selenium

Tags: python, django, selenium-webdriver

So I'm tryig to use this tool:
 - http://selenose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

No go. Still my driver is connecting wrong server. Except that documentation is incomplete or maybe even erroneous, that's what I did.

1. pip install selenose
2. create setup.cfg (root of the project) that has following content:

   - http://sprunge.us/dgRL (link is dead)
3. Then create a test file (test-run.py) with following content:

   - http://sprunge.us/LVIc (link is dead)
4. Then I'm trying to run (root of the project) test by issuing either:

   - nosetests test-run.py

   or

   - ./manage.py test test-run.py

Both of them end up with:
   WebDriverException: Message: u'Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output: (...)***

Any hint what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  I see no reason to use Selenose .  Why not just use the regular Python selenium bindings?

Comment: Dear djangofan, I asked why it's not working, not what should I use or should not. Thank you.

Comment: Ok.  I had never heard of the related project until now: https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

After few days of playing with selenose, I have only one good answer. This tech probably works well with django-jenkins, but if you are trying use it on your own. You are going to have problems sir. ;) But if yo decide to use it and it works, good. If it doesn't probably it will be better to write your own nose plugin that will do your job than trying to figure out why this one is not working.

This is an approach I took. I just scrapped all selenose code and have written few scripts/plugins on my own. As there is no real help on internet with the issues and examples from documantatio usually are not working.

Comment: I checked out selenose, and for setup without django-jenkins, I see no point in using it, as it causes slower start-up of testing process. I just use ordinary screen (or tmux, or just a background process) to run selenium server from shell prompt (java -jar selenium-*.jar) and that's enough. Server stays online in the backgronud and there is no startup penalty. I guess selenose may have its uses as it makes things simpler for sysadmin, but I don't think it makes them easier (=faster, more efficient) for programmer, who can setup his/hers own tools. django-nose looks like a way to go.